# LARAVEL - Retrieve relationship in hasOne returns null

Tags: laravel

There are 3 tables : programmes - lots - fichiers

Fichier.php :

```
public function lot()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Lot::class);
}

public function scopeCategorie($query, $categorie)
{
    return $query->select('url')->where('categorie', $categorie);
}
```

Lot.php :

```
public function programme()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Programme::class);
}
public function plan()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Fichier::class,'lot_id','id')->categorie('lot_plan_vente');
}
```

Programme.php :

```
public function lots()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Lot::class,'id_programme','id')->with('plan')->get();
}
```

When i dump in programme controller :

```
$programmes->lots
```

i can see an null 'plan' value for every lot.

But if i dump :

```
foreach($programme->lots as $lot) {
            if(isset($lot->plan->url)) {
                dump($lot->plan->url);
            }
        }
```

i can see the plan value, the relationship is retrieved.
I guess i'm missing something, can't figure out what...

Any help appreciated, thanks !

Comment: you are supposed to be returning a relationship object not a result from the relationship method, remove the `get` call at the least

Comment: Good eyes @lagbox!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Programme` class doesn't return a relationship instance in the `lots()` method. It's returning a `collection`.

```
public function lots()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Lot::class,'id_programme','id')->with('plan');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. With this tip i now retrieve a collection with relationship for each lot but still null

Answer (score 0):

Porgramme.php

```
public function lots()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Lot::class,'id_programme','id');
}
```

---

```
$programme->with(["lots.plan"])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply ! This one still returns a null plan while the $lot->plan->url returns the value